# jQuery image resizing (file size and dimensions) while loading

Tags: jquery, image

For the example I have 2500x2500 pixels image. But i know that i need it to be shown in 1000x1000. 
Tried using CSS, but it loads the full size image and then resizes it, which uses too much data.

Comment: You can't resize image with jQuery, well not in the way you want it. For resizing an image and serving it as resized you need to make that on the server side (for example with php), and jQuery will work on the client side (the browser) :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for most likely can't be done in jQuery either. By the time the javascript is executed, the full-sized image has already been downloaded. jQuery can't talk to the server (see exception below) to tell it to resize the image before downloading it. You will most likely need to use a server-side language, such as PHP, to do what you want.

There is an upcoming exception to this: the new [picture](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#the-picture-element) element in HTML, which will allow you to select varying sizes of images depending on a number of conditions. Support for this is currently limited, but since this element will default to a standard img element, there is no downside to using it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This will resize the image:

```
<img width="1000px" height="1000px"/>
```

or

```
img{
 width:1000px;
 height:1000px;
}
```